# Figcaption has margin-top when using transition, can't figure out why

Tags: html, css

I'm using figure and figcaption to transition a heading over an image, and the transition works fine, but the figcaption background is sitting just outsite of the actual image by a few pixels (at the top).

I've looked over my code and changed margin, padding, and position settings, but I can't figure out why the figcaption background has been moved down when it transitions.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<figure>
    <img src="images/melon.jpg" alt="melon"></a>
    <figcaption>
        <h3><a href="mywebsite.com">Live Demo or Buy Now</a></h3>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and here's my css

```
figure {
cursor: pointer;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
float: left;}

figure:hover figcaption {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
bottom: 0;

-webkit-transform: rotate(0);
-moz-transform: rotate(0);
-o-transform: rotate(0);
-ms-transform: rotate(0);
transform: rotate(0);
}

figure a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
figcaption {
background-color: rgba(46, 204, 113, .6);
height: 183px;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: -100%;
width: 360px;

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in;
transition: all .4s ease-in;
}
figcaption h3 {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300px;
left: -100%;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 63px;
padding: 10px 20px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

-webkit-transition: all .4s;
-moz-transition: all .4s;
-o-transition: all .4s;
-ms-transition: all .4s;
transition: all .4s;

-webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
-moz-transition-delay: .5s;
-o-transition-delay: .5s;
-ms-transition-delay: .5s;
transition-delay: .5s;
}
figure:hover h3 {
left: 0;}
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding the problem you're having. If you look at http://jsbin.com/OPeLAhO/1/, what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
figure img {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much, I spent a solid hour trying to figure it out. I had no idea the solution was going to be so easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can Add like this

```
Figcaption{margin:0; padding:0}
```